# NSRangeException exception in NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate event of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` that uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` as data source.

The core data store is updated in multiple background threads running in parallel (each thread using it's own `NSManagedObjectContext`).

The main thread observes the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`
notification and updates it's context with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`.

Sometimes it happens that the `NSFetchedResultsController` sends an 
`NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` event with an indexPath that does not exist
anymore at that point.

For example: The result set of the fetched results controller contains
1 section with 4 objects. The first object is deleted in one thread.
The last object is updated in a different thread. Then sometimes the
following happens:

- controllerWillChangeContent: is called.
- controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: is called with
  type = NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete, indexPath.row = 0.
- controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: is called with
  type = NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate, indexPath.row = 3.

But the fetched results controller contains only 3 objects now, and if call

```
MyManagedObject *obj = [controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

to update the table view cell according to the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`
event, this crashes with a `NSRangeException` exception.

Thank you for any help or ideas!

Comment: Ole Begemann has a blog entry about this issue: http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/ (FWIW, I prefer your fix to his.)

Comment: @KristopherJohnson: Thanks for the feedback and the link (I had the problem only *occasionally*, and that blog entry contains good information why the problem can occur). - And yes, *reloading* the table row causes the cell to be redrawn, which is sometimes not desired.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have now found a solution for my problem. In the case of an update event, there is no need to call

```
[self.controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

because the updated object is already supplied as the *anObject* parameter to the `-controller:didChangedObject:...` delegate.

I have therefore replaced `-configureCell:atIndexPath:` by a `-configureCell:withObject:` method that uses the updated object directly. This seems to work without problems.

The code looks now like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withObject:(MyManagedObject *)myObj
{
    cell.textLabel.text = myObj.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    [self configureCell:cell withObject:[self.controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
    /* ... */           
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withObject:anObject];
        break;
    /* ... */           
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible improvement: if `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` returns nil, then that row is not onscreen and there is no need to call `configureCell:withObject:`.

Comment: ```cellForRowAtIndexPath:``` cannot return nil. That will generate an inconsistency! If ```cellForRowAtIndexPath:``` is called, that is because ```numberOfRowsInSection:``` is returning > 0

Comment: @CarlosRicardo: The UITableView method cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range. - What you probably mean is the UITableViewDataSource method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: which must return a valid cell and not nil. But that method is not used here.

Comment: Yes, that's the method I'm talking about, is there any other one with the same signature that I wasn't aware of? Because I see that above: ```tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]```. I think I'm missing something here

Comment: @CarlosRicardo: `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` calls the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of UITableView. - You are confusing it with the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of the UITableViewDataSource delegate protocol, which would be called as `[dataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

Comment: The worst case happened in my app: `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` sometimes causes `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called so the bad `indexPath` still gets passed to `[self.controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

Answer (score 9):

This is actually quite common because of the [bug in Apple's boiler plate code for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/), which you get when you create a new master/detail project with Core Data enabled:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

## Solution #1: Use `anObject`

Why query the fetched results controller and risk using an incorrect index path when the object is already given to you? [Martin R recommends this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503330/35690) as well.

Simply change the helper method `configureCell:atIndexPath:` from taking an index path to take in the actual object that was modified:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withObject:(NSManagedObject *)object {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}
```

In cell for row, use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    return cell;
}
```

Finally, in the update use:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
             withObject:anObject];
    break;
```

## Solution #2: Use `newIndexPath`

As of iOS 7.1, both `indexPath` and `newIndexPath` are passed in when a NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate happens.

Simply keep the default implementation's usage of indexPath when calling cellForRowAtIndexPath, but change the second index path that is sent in to newIndexPath:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
            atIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    break;
```

## Solution #3: Reload rows at index path

[Ole Begemann's solution](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/) is to reload the index paths. Replace the call to configure cell with a call to reload rows:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    break;
```

There are two disadvantages with this method:

1. By calling reload rows, it will call cellForRow, which in turn calls dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, which will reuse an existing cell, possibly **getting rid of important state** (e.g. if the cell is in the middle of being dragged a la [Mailbox style](http://www.mailboxapp.com)).
2. It will incorrectly **try and reload a cell that isn't visible**. In Apple's original code, [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) will return "`nil` if the cell is not visible or `indexPath` is out of range." Therefore it would be more correct to check with [indexPathsForVisibleRows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForVisibleRows) before calling reload rows.

---

## Reproducing the bug

1. Create a new master/detail project with core data in Xcode 6.4.
2. Add a title attribute to the core data `event` object.
3. Populate the table with several records (e.g. in `viewDidLoad` run this code)

   ```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
   for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
       [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
       [newManagedObject setValue:[@(i) stringValue] forKey:@"title"];
   }
   [context save:nil];
   ```
4. Change configure cell to show the title attribute:

   ```
   - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"], [object valueForKey:@"title"]];
   }
   ```
5. In addition to adding a record when the new button is tapped, update the last item (Note: this can be done before or after the item is created, but make sure to do it before save is called!):

   ```
   // update the last item
   NSArray *objects = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
   NSManagedObject *lastObject = [objects lastObject];
   [lastObject setValue:@"updated" forKey:@"title"];
   ```
6. Run the app. You should see five items.
7. Tap the new button. You will see that a new item is added to the top, and that the last item does not have the text "updated," even though it should have had it. If you force the cell to reload (e.g. by scrolling the cell off the screen), it will have the text "updated."
8. Now implement one of the three solutions outlined above and in addition to an item being added, the last item's text will change to "updated."